Desktop freezes randomly with nothing in the logs. How to investigate?
I recently acquired a second hand desktop. I installed a brand new Debian Bookworm on it. I'm getting random freezes and can't find anything in the logs. I also got a spurious reboot today.
By random, I mean I have no idea what circumstances trigger this. I was not doing anything CPU or I/O intensive. And I have been doing Xbox emulation or copying entire partitions from one hard drive to another without issue.

No SSH access, no ping, no Magic SysRq keys

journalctl doesn't provide anything. No line before the crash.

I don't see anything in Xorg logs either.

memtest passes


Hardware specs, FWIIW:

AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-Core Processor          Unknown CPU @ 3.4GHz
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] (rev cf)
24 GB RAM
28 GB swap (empty)
240 GB SSD for /
1 TB HDD for /home

lm-sensors reports 82°C (180°F) on the SSD but this has to be a sensor issue because the case is well ventilated and the disk is not hot at all, it seems even cool to the touch. Also, the reported temperature is too constant to be true, already at 82°C just after power on. I guess a faulty sensor could cause a security shutdown by reporting a high temperature but not a reboot or a freeze, right?
lm-sensors also reports HDD 30°C, Tctl 47°C and Tdie 27°C which is normal AFAIK. Besides, nothing "feels" hot in the case.
This definitely sounds like a hardware problem. Any idea how to find the culprit, apart from changing each piece one after the other? Any diagnosis tool I could use?

Can you go to the virtual console through Ctrl + Alt + F1~12? It seems not to a problem of lack of the RAM.

@PICOPress I'll try when it happens but I don't think so. I couldn't even use the Magix SysRq keys. I'll double-check that too and update but I'm pretty sure.

Sysrq is only available on production PC when kernel.sysrq in the file /etc/sysctl.conf is 1. And If not a hardware problem, it must be able.

@PICOPress Magic SysRq keys are enabled. Edited the question because it happened again and I had no ping. I think I was wrong when I wrote I had ping the other day. I'm facing a HW problem I have no idea how to track from software.
